# How to pass variables from email?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, html-email

I have developed a contact form which incorporates CI form validation, email helper and class. When the user sends the information the client will receive a HTML email with this information. I have already created a separate view with the HTML table structure and this is built through a string in the controller [code below]. Is there any way of passing what the user has sent into this HTML form? For example in my email I have:

```
-You have received an email from $name<br>
-Message $message<br>
-You can reply to them at $email
```

It would be great if someone could guide me. I have included important snippets of code as a guide.

**View:**

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<div id="contact">
<?php

    echo $message;
    echo validation_errors();

    echo form_open('contact/send_email');

    //Name field
    echo form_label('Name: ', 'name');
        $data = array (
            'name' => 'name',
            'id' => 'name',
            'value' => set_value('name')
        );
    echo form_input($data);

    echo form_submit('submit', 'Send');

    echo form_close();
```

**Controller:**

At the top of this code is the form validation and if else statements, and this is what happens when it has passed validation checks:

```
}else{
    $data['message'] = 'The email has successfully been sent';

    $html_email = $this->load->view('html_email', $data, true);

    //load the email class
    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from(set_value('email'), set_value('name'));
    $this->email->to('email@hotmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Message from Website');
    $this->email->message($html_email);

    $this->email->send();

    //if error from library will send us metadata
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();

    $data['page_title'] = 'Contact';
    $data['content'] = 'contact';   
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

Comment: I think this works and is this the right way: Add in "<?php echo $_POST['name'] ?>" wherever i want the values in the html form?

Comment: what you will have in the $data....

Comment: Hi there, Its the trigger for returning the view with the dynamic data being passed into it

Comment: you can do one thing build two view files one is contact.php which will had form and everything when the user submits the form it will goes to one function in controller which will call another view file in that you are going to get data whatever u want using $_POST. Prepare how ever u want html email in that view and send that view file using u r send mail function.....

Comment: Thanks, i have all the above what you said set up ready, and thought i will give echoing $_POST['name'] a go and works a treat. Is there any downfalls to this method or is this the best/only way? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Balboa i will write my comment as answer accept it..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing things the CodeIgniter way you should use `$this->input->post('name')` instead of `$_POST['name']`

To get the data to your view just add

`$data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');`

Before you load your view. This will allow you to print the `$name` variable in the view as in your initial statement. I.e. in the view:

`You have a message from <?=$name?>`

In the controller I would also change `set_value('name')` for `$this->input->post('name')`.

Comment: I am only a novice user of CI and this has helped a lot, I changed from POST to what you said above and works great- Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. That's what StackOverflow is for :)

Answer (score 0):

From the example above- it was simple as adding: echo $_POST['name']
into the html form. Hope this may help other people and thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use $_POST['name'} in the html form file.